# How to properly encapsulate access to different database systems having (almost) the same schema?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, entity-framework

Starting situation: There is an existing database schema in MS SQL which is quite identical to an existing schema in MySQL (database first - cannot be changed as widely installed). However they can slightly differ in the datatyoe being used for the corresponding column. That database systems have to be accessed via C#.

Problem: How can I properly encapsulate access to any of the two from the application's point of view, i.e. that a programmer must not be aware if he queries a MySQL or a MSSQL database?

Example: I have a table, say MyTable, having a primary column "Id" of bigint  and a column "data" of varchar.

My idea was to use EntityFramework (version 6) to automatically generate all the CRUD operations. So I created a .edmx model for both MySQL and MSSQL which i wanted to inject into the logic layer (i.e. the resulting context). But I noticed that in case of MySQL, the Id (bigint) was mapped to decimal whereas in MS SQL it was mapped to long. Now I wonder if this EF approach is suitable as there are different datatypes for the same (named) column (of the same named table) in the two database systems as well. For that reason a colleague favors to write all the statements ourselves as it is done in the legacy software version, i.e. to not use EF at all but to only offer a facade method that is implemented by plain SQL both for MS SQL and MySQL.

However I'm not a fan of writing all the sql statements by myself...

As I mentioned above I need to encapsulate the database access - but if there are different mappings for the the different database systems - how to do that properly? I could build up a facade in front of the EF model and implement (datatype, say API) adapters if there is any difference between the MSSQL and MySQL mapping, but this approach leads to an abstraction of an abstraction I think.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that you want your application to be able to switch between SQL Server & MySQL, so that one installation uses MySQL as a backend and another installation of the same app uses SQL Server?

Comment: Exactly! We have an equipment database we have to query first. Example: "Give me the location of equipment A". Result: "MS SQL database on server XY" or "MySQL database on server Z". Then the application has to either query MS SQL or MySQL. The schemas on both systems are almost identical - but not to 100 procent. That's why there is plain sql used currently.

Comment: Did this for SQL Server and SQL Compact with EF6, but those two have very similar data types. Perhaps check also other other ORM frameworks (Hibernate ..).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested: We managed to use a single context as both database structures are almost identical. One only has to pass the corresponding connection string to the Entites (DbContext) constructor.
So there are two edmx models: One for MySQL and one for MSSQL whereas the concrete model classes are only on one side (MSSQL in our case).